# Manipular variável

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, glob

Estou encontrando um arquivo .csv com a biblioteca glob

```
import glob
local = "C:\\Users\\rdf_8\\Downloads\\*.csv"
arquivo = glob.glob(local)
arquivo = str(arquivo).strip('[]')
print(arquivo)
```

Consigo encontrar o arquivo e caminho com sucesso.

```
'C:\\Users\\rdf_8\\Downloads\\test.csv'
```

Porém quando uso o metodo no Pandas para tratar a tabela é acrescentado "\" em cada caminho do diretório.

```
import pandas as pd

tabela = pd.read_csv(arquivo, sep=";")
```

Apresenta o erro

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "'C:\\\\Users\\\\rdf_8\\\\Downloads\\\\test.csv'"
```

Existe uma forma de tratar esse erro?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: `glob()` retorna uma lista. Usando o módulo [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/os.path.html) com a linha `from os.path import abspath`,  apague a linha `arquivo = str(arquivo).strip('[]')` e imprima o nome do primeiro arquivo da lista assim `print(abspath(arquivo[0]))`.

Comment: Entendi Augusto, sua dica foi preciosa. Funcionou aqui e melhorou meu código. Assim eu consigo usar sempre o ultimo arquivo .csv, sem me preocupar em apagar os outros arquivos .csv na pasta

Answer (score -2):

Resolvi transformando em uma string com o método join()

```
import glob
local = "C:\\Users\\rdf_8\\Downloads\\*.csv"
arquivo = glob.glob(local)
dir = "".join(arquivo)
print(dir)
C:\Users\rdf_8\Downloads\StreamProbe_undefined_2022_1_16.csv
```

Comment: Coloque mais um arquivo com a extensão `.csv` na mesma pasta e veja o resultado.

Comment: Tenho esse retorno, que irá apresentar um erro. No caso que esta agora só esta funcionando com um arquivo csv na pasta. Estou apagando o arquivo CSV no final do meu código, para que sempre tenha um arquivo
`C:\Users\rdf_8\Downloads\outroArquivo.csvC:\Users\rdf_8\Downloads\text.csv`

Comment: Então, leia esse [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/540235/manipular-vari%c3%a1vel/540248?noredirect=1#comment970745_540235) que soluciona o seu problema e possiveis problemas que podem aparecer.